# Is "sketchy" appropriate for an IELTS Academic essay?

Tags: word-usage, ielts

While preparing for IELTS Academic, I was practicing [Writing Task 1](http://www.ieltsbuddy.com/ielts-map.html).
In the task it is said:

> Below is a map of the city of Brandfield. ...

Commonly, the first sentence of an essay should rephrase the task, so I came up with:

> The map presents a sketchy scheme of ...

By *sketchy* I mean something that contains few details, as according to [Cambridge definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sketchy).

But I'm afraid that *sketchy* is not the appropriate word for the formal writing, and I am certainly sure that IELTS Academic essays should be formal.

Research before asking:
1. Google responds to "sketchy meaning" with 2 slang dictionaries out of 3 top results.
2. In 4 out of 5 first not slang dictionaries that Google gave (Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, Cambridge, The free dictionary, Macmillan) the word *sketchy* has an informal meaning among others.
3. However, in [SkELL](https://sketchengine.co.uk) there are 126 entries of *sketchy* in British National Corpus.

The question: Is this appropriate to use *sketchy* in this case?

Comment: sketchy will generally be taken to imply a negative connotation

Comment: Just say *The map **outlines** [whatever it presents a sketchy picture of]* and move on. Not everyone will even recognise the relatively modern extended figurative use *(questionable, iffy, immoral, etc.)*, but that *definitely* wouldn't be desirable in a formal context, so it's best to play safe and not use the word at all, even if all you want it to mean is the straightforward *outlined without much detail, as a sketch* sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"sketchy" for me has the same connotation as "dodgy" - a slang term that means that something or someone is of a questionable nature - for example, a "sketchy neighbourhood" would not be a place one would want to live. Slang or not, the way in which you are using it doesn't seem to fit the context - to my ear at least.

I'm sure there are many alternative ways of phrasing this, but seeing that you are describing what the map depicts, and the map is only a rough draft, the phrase "The map presents a rough outline of..." seems more fitting, and less entrenched in slang.

Comment: I think the meaning he was going for is more like the one used in the phrase "the details are a bit sketchy at the moment", meaning not particularly thought-out. But this is not a meaning that comes naturally in all contexts, and the meaning of "dodgy" is one that I would jump to in the context OP used it in, but I can't articulate why. In either case, I would expect to see them used in informal environments rather than an essay. Rough outline is definitely better for this context, IMHO.